# Double mapping JSON to list

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

I have a problem with showing data from JSON.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
data1 = [
    {
        id:'1',
        name: 'one',
        on: [
            {
                id:'1.1',
                type: 'Anna',
            },
            {
                id:'1.2',
                type: 'John',
            },
        ],

    },
    {
        id:'2',
        name: 'two',
        on: [
            {
                id:'1.1',
                type: 'John',
            },
            {
                id:'1.2',
                type: 'Anna',
            },
        ],

    },
]
```

I'm getting a JSON from local API by axios. This way works great in other tables. With this JSON I've try do this this way:

```
getData = () => {
    axios
      .get("Localhost", { params : {token : this.state.token }})
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(data1 => ({
          id: `${data1.id}`,
          name: `${data1.name}`,
          onid: `${data1.on.id}`,
          ontype: `${data1.on.type}`,
        }))
      )
      .then(data1 => {
        this.setState({ data1 });
      })
  }
```

and then in render i try to map it:

```
<ol>
    {data1.map(user => {
      const { id, name } = user;
      return (
        <li key={id}>
          {name}
          {data1.on.map(user2 => {
            const { onid, ontype } = user2;
            return <li key={onid}> {ontype}</li>;
          })}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ol>
```

but the map for data1.on doesn't work

I expect that data will appear like this:

1. One

   1. Anna
   2. John
2. Two

   1. John
   2. Anna

How should I do that?

Comment: Hi Bartek, just submitted you a solution to update your .map. Let me know if that works :)

Comment: nope :/  `TypeError: item.on is undefined`

Comment: wait whaaaatt :(. in my sandbox, does it look the way you want it to look?

Comment: yes, it looks great! maybe the problem is in axios function? but in firefox console get response looks like data in question

Comment: Oh yeah! In your response, you are using           onid: `${data1.on.id}`,
          ontype: `${data1.on.type}`,. But your json is using just on and type instead. I see, I was working off your json data not what you had in state. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Try my answer now, I changed it to onid and ontype. That should fix it for you.

Comment: now `TypeError: id2.map is not a function` , i thing data1 in this.state doesn't look like json response from axios but don't now how to fix this

Comment: Hmmmm, wherei s id2.map() coming from? That doesnt look like something you put in the code above, or anything Im using below.

Comment: i fix this, your  map function works but i doesn't need to map data 1 in axios function just put ` then(response => {
        this.setState({ data1 : response.data });
      }  `

Comment: okay yeah that'll make it cleaner. So now we are using just id and type again right? No more onid and ontype. Is it still giving you any error :o?

Comment: i used "item.on" and it works, yout first answer was correct, the problem was in axios function

Comment: Oh that is awesome Bartek! Thanks for following-up, if you dont mind, could you please mark my solution as the answer if you found it to be correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to rework your map. Try something like this:

```
  <ol>
    {this.state.data1.map(item => {
      return (
        <li>
          {item.name.toUpperCase()}
          <ol>
            {item.on.map(person => {
              return <li>{person.type}</li>;
            })}
          </ol>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ol>
);
```

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-ellis-76bdv

Comment: Hi Christopher, in your solution the return is implicit, you can leave it in a one-line function. But I would recommend adding a key prop to your list components so that you don't get a "missing key" warning.